# Adobe LiveCyle - when to use connection properties for ServiceClientFactory in WebLogic?

Tags: java, adobe, livecycle

When making a connection from Java to Adobe LiveCycle ES 2.5, the [Setting connection properties](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/livecycle/9.0/programLC/help/index.htm?content=000501.html) page lists the default connection properties you should use depending on your server type.

For WebLogic, it is this:

```
Properties ConnectionProps = new Properties();
connectionProps.setProperty(ServiceClientFactoryProperties.DSC_DEFAULT_EJB_ENDPOINT, "t3://localhost:7001");
connectionProps.setProperty(ServiceClientFactoryProperties.DSC_TRANSPORT_PROTOCOL,ServiceClientFactoryProperties.DSC_EJB_PROTOCOL);
connectionProps.setProperty(ServiceClientFactoryProperties.DSC_SERVER_TYPE, "WebLogic");
connectionProps.setProperty(ServiceClientFactoryProperties.DSC_CREDENTIAL_USERNAME, "administrator");
connectionProps.setProperty(ServiceClientFactoryProperties.DSC_CREDENTIAL_PASSWORD, "password")

...
ServiceClientFactory myFactory = ServiceClientFactory.createInstance(connectionProps);
```

My problem is this: on our WebLogic server, the above fails with the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: t3://localhost:7001: Destination unreachable; nested exception is:
```

However, if I simply ignore connectionProps, it works:

```
ServiceClientFactory myFactory = ServiceClientFactory.createInstance();
```

SO, what is going on here? Is Adobe wrong, and you don't use connectionProps for WebLogic, or is there some WebLogic configuration that we are missing? What does it mean when I use ServiceClientFactory.createInstance() - without connectionProps?

Thanks for any advice!

Rob
:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer given on the this [Google Group Post](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en-GB#!topic/livecycle/NRUcQ-BHj-8): only need the configuration values if you are connecting to a LiveCycle running in a different JVM.

Rob

:)